# How to configure multiple directories, sub-directories in Snakemake?

Tags: python, bioinformatics, snakemake

I have SAM files that are in the following structure:

```
MyFolder
├── 534897345_Lane1
│   ├── Sample9729
│   │   └── Aligned.out.sam
│   ├── Sample082340
│   │   └── Aligned.out.sam
│   ├── Sample098490220ABN
│       └── Aligned.out.sam
└── 534897345_Lane2
    ├── XY97289
    │   └── Aligned.out.sam
    ├── IJBND97824
    │   └── Aligned.out.sam
    ├── something90784
        └── Aligned.out.sam
```

I need to pass each SAM file into its own FastQC job, and its own HTSeq-Count job. Later on, I will also be merging these sam files together to call variants.

I'm having a hard time figuring out how to programmatically access the sam files while keeping their lane and sample name identity in Snakemake. Here is what I have right now (doesn't work):

```
lanes, samples = glob_wildcards('path/to/MyFolder/' + '{lane}/{sample}/Aligned.out.sam')

rule all: 
    input:
        expand('logs/fastqc/{lane}/{sample}.log', lane=lanes, sample=samples)

rule fastqc: 
    input:

    output:
        html='/fastqc/{lane}/{sample}.html',
        zip='/fastqc/{lane}/{sample}_fastqc.zip'
    threads: 1
    log: 'logs/fastqc/{lane}/{sample}.log'
    resources: mem_mb=8000, cpus=1
    wrapper: 
        '''
        0.77.0/bio/fastqc
        '''
```

It seems like the `expand()` function tries to construct every combination of files, so for example 534897345_Lane1/XY97289/Aligned.out.sam comes up as missing as it should. How do I go about constructing the samples in Snakemake? Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct that expand does all the combinations (aka the product) of the wildcards. I'm not sure if there's a snakemake-centric approach, but I would use python list comprehension and zip:

```
rule all:
    input: 
        [f'logs/fastqc/{lane}/{sample}.log' \
         for lane, sample in zip(lanes, samples)]
```

Update: The original poster figured out that you can do this in [`expand()`](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/snakefiles/rules.html#the-expand-function) by passing `zip` as the combinatoric function:

```
expand('output/featureCounts/{lane}/{sample}.log', zip, lane=lanes, sample=samples)
```

Comment: Thanks, I just realized that expand has a zip argument which I used below:

`expand('output/featureCounts/{lane}/{sample}.log', zip, lane=lanes, sample=samples)`